# Why does the terminal freeze when running a C program?

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I am trying to read the input form the user in terminal raw mode.

Here's the function that enables the raw mode and disables some of the escape characters and all. It also references the disableRawMode which is used to re-enter the cannonical mode after the input has been read:

```
void enableRawMode() {
     if (tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &orig_termios) == -1) 
        die("tcgetattr");
    atexit(disableRawMode);
    struct termios raw = orig_termios;
    raw.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | ICRNL | INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON);
    raw.c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
    raw.c_cflag |= (CS8);
    raw.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN | ISIG);
    raw.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    raw.c_cc[VTIME] = 1;
    if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &raw) == -1)
        die("tcsetattr");
}
```

There are also some other functions(editorReadKey & editorprocessKeypress) to read the keypress and process the character input:

```
char editorReadKey() {
    int nread;
    char c;
    while ((nread = read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1) != 1)) {
        if (nread == -1 && errno != EAGAIN) 
            die("read");
    }
}

void editorProcessKeypress() {
    char c = editorReadKey();
    switch (c) {
    case CTRL_KEY('q'):
        exit(0);
        break;
    }
}
```

But when I call the functions in the main program:

```
int main(void) {    
    enableRawMode();
    while (1) {
        editorRefreshScreen();
        editorProcessKeypress();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My terminal just freezes up and I've to restart it to get it back working. Any reasons as to why that might be happening?

Comment: There is a difference between "when compiling" and "when running".

Comment: If you insert an output in the endless loop inside `main()` how often do you see that output?

Comment: Sorry about that. It so happens that English isn't my first language and I'm still getting used to it. Edited the question.

Comment: @Yunnosch I am only using the infinite loop because I want to read the input till 'q' is pressed. In which case, I suppose the loop will terminate.

Comment: `char c = editorReadKey();` My guess is that this should have been an int.

Comment: You don't return anything from `editorReadKey()` and the C compiler just accepts that. This means that none of your key handling will ever trigger, so your code never does anything, and therefore looks frozen. Always build C code with `-Wall`

Comment: @thatotherguy My bad. I wonder how I missed it. Thank you for the help, man!

Comment: You missed it because of a lack of `-Wall` :P

Comment: @thatotherguy Haha. As it turns out, I had specified a return value in my program but somehow it missed here. The problem stays as it is.

Comment: please post a complete program so someone can download and take a look

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example does what you want. Output is minimal, since this is the point :)

```
terminal info saved
raw mode will be set now
Enter 'q' to exit!

terminal configuration restored
```

The program just saves the terminal config, enter raw mode and read from input until a 'q' is read or the user press control-C. Then the terminal is reset and the configuration restored.

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

typedef struct termios Termios;

void        editorProcessKeypress();
char        editorReadKey();
void        editorRefreshScreen();
void        enableRawMode(Termios*);
void        gameOver();
int         getMode(Termios*);
int         setMode(Termios*);

int main(void)
{ 
    Termios original_termios;
    Termios raw;
    if ( getMode(&original_termios) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not get terminal info");
        return(-1);
    }
    printf("terminal info saved\n");

    enableRawMode(&raw);

    printf("Enter 'q' to exit!\n");
    editorRefreshScreen();
    char in = editorReadKey();

    while( in != 'q' )
    {
           editorRefreshScreen();
           in = editorReadKey();
    };

    if ( setMode(&original_termios) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Could not reset terminal. Please run 'tput reset'!");
        return(-1);
    }
    printf("\nterminal configuration restored\n");
    return 0;
};

void enableRawMode(Termios* raw)
{
    raw->c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | ICRNL | INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON);
    raw->c_oflag &= ~(OPOST);
    raw->c_cflag |= (CS8);
    raw->c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN ) | ISIG;
    raw->c_cc[VINTR] = 3;
    raw->c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
    raw->c_cc[VTIME] = 10;

    signal(SIGINT, gameOver);

    printf("raw mode will be set now\n");
    if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, raw) < 0)
        printf("raw mode NOT set!!\n");
    fflush(stdin);
};

char editorReadKey() {
    int nread;
    char c = 0;
    while ((nread = read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1) != 1)) {
        if (nread == -1 && errno != EAGAIN) 
            return 0;
    };
    return c;
};


void        editorRefreshScreen()
{
    return;
};


void        gameOver()
{
    Termios reset;
    reset.c_iflag =  ~IGNCR | ICRNL | INPCK  | ISTRIP | IXON | BRKINT | ICANON;
    reset.c_oflag = ECHO | OPOST;
    reset.c_lflag = ECHO | ICANON | IEXTEN;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &reset);
    printf("\n^C: Aborting... Issue a 'tput reset' if terminal not ok\n");
    exit(1);
};


int         getMode( Termios* term )
{
        return tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, term);
};


int         setMode(Termios* term)
{
        return tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, term);
};
```